# GetPixel Function returns incorrect value when getting value in handle

Tags: c++

I have used 2 main functions as below, Main1 function gets the correct RGB color code of all points on the screen, but when I use main2 function, it still gets the correct coordinates of the point according to the application I need to get but return wrong RGB value
==> Please help to fix this error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main1() {
    POINT pos;
    int R;
    int G;
    int B;
    while (1) {
        GetCursorPos(&pos);
        HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
        COLORREF color = GetPixel(hDC, pos.x, pos.y);
        R = GetRValue(color);
        G = GetGValue(color);
        B = GetBValue(color);
        std::cout << "x : " << pos.x << ", y : " << pos.y << ", R : " << R << ", G : " << G << ", B : " << B << endl;
        ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
int main2() {
    POINT pos;
    int R;
    int G;
    int B;
    while (1) {
        LPCWSTR window_title = L"HxD";
        HWND hWND = FindWindow(NULL, window_title);
        while (!hWND)
        {
            hWND = FindWindow(NULL, window_title);
            cout << "not found window"<<endl;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        GetCursorPos(&pos);
        ScreenToClient(hWND, &pos);
        HDC hDC = GetDC(hWND);
        COLORREF color = GetPixel(hDC, pos.x, pos.y);
        R = GetRValue(color);
        G = GetGValue(color);
        B = GetBValue(color);
        std::cout << "x : " << pos.x << ", y : " << pos.y << ", R : " << R << ", G : " << G << ", B : " << B << endl;
        ReleaseDC(hWND, hDC);
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: error picture]

Comment: It's said that "Insanity is doing the same thing over and over and expecting different results.” So if `FindWindow(NULL, window_title)` fails, why do you think doing it again will succeed? And if it fails, why do you continue as if nothing happend?

Comment: If you look at HxD with Spy++ you'll see it has many child windows in addition to the main window. Perhaps you're looking at the wrong one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if findwindow fails, it will print the screen "not found window", when the program has found the coordinates, it means hWND != NULL

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have checked with "Calculator" and "Notepad" and the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as your program except it grabs the window under the cursor and prints the process id that window was created by so you can see when it changes.

You'll find it works on many windows like the Desktop, HxD, Visual Studio, and Notepad but not Calculator or Chrome. I didn't investigate that since this works with the program you initially asked about and if you're interested it gives you something to dig into. [WindowFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint) has some restrictions so it may be returning the wrong window. `ChildWindowFromPoint` might be a place to start.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    POINT pos {};
    DWORD pid = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        GetCursorPos(&pos);
        HWND hwnd = WindowFromPoint(pos);
        if (hwnd)
        {
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
            ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pos);
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            if (hdc)
            {
                COLORREF color = GetPixel(hdc, pos.x, pos.y);
                std::cout << "pid: " << pid
                    << " [" << pos.x << "," << pos.y << "]"
                    << " R: " << static_cast<int>(GetRValue(color))
                    << " G: " << static_cast<int>(GetGValue(color))
                    << " B: " << static_cast<int>(GetBValue(color))
                    << "\n";
                ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
            }
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: if using WindowFromPoint returns wrong coordinates for application with many windows, so I combined findwindow and WindowFromPoint

Answer (score 0):

Although it does not meet the requirements, but I have to accept it, maybe getDC can't be used together with getpixel

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    POINT pos;
    int R;
    int G;
    int B;
    while (1) {
        LPCWSTR window_title = L"HxD";
        HWND hWND = FindWindow(NULL, window_title);
        while (!hWND)
        {
            hWND = FindWindow(NULL, window_title);
            cout << "not found window" << endl;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        GetCursorPos(&pos);
        HWND hWndxy = WindowFromPoint(pos);
        ScreenToClient(hWND, &pos);
        if (pos.x >= 0 && pos.y >= 0)
        {
            HDC hDC = GetDC(hWndxy);
            COLORREF color = GetPixel(hDC, pos.x, pos.y);
            R = GetRValue(color);
            G = GetGValue(color);
            B = GetBValue(color);
            std::cout << "x : " << pos.x << ", y : " << pos.y << ", R : " << R << ", G : " << G << ", B : " << B << endl;
            ReleaseDC(hWndxy, hDC);
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.